# Star Wars: Battlefront (2015) freezes computer on launch

Tags: technical-issues, pc, star-wars-battlefront-2015

Computer Specs...

- i5 6600k (not overclocked... yet)
- Gigabyte gtx 1060 6g
- 16GB of DDR4 ram at 2666 mhz
- MSI Z170 - A Pro Motherboard

Whenever I try to start battlefront my computer freezes. Nothing responds, and I can't bring up task manager. Once I restart the computer via the reset button, a lot of my computer settings are changed, specifically graphics card setting such as the fan speed curve.

My best theory is that it is crashing due to the graphics card. The thing is that I have played this game on this computer before. Though around 10 days after the last successful launch there was a graphics driver update.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the game and origin, clean installing the lastest graphics driver. Looking through the windows event logs for a clue as to what is happening, which didn't give any clues. There were no errors associated with the launches other than that the computer did not shutdown properly. I've disconnected my secondary screen and put in a command to run the game in windowed borderless mode.

I'm at a bit of a loss as to what to look for next.

Comment: I agree it sounds like a driver issue -- those specs are more than enough to run the game. Is there a way to downgrade your graphics driver easily? (This is why I don't update graphics drivers unless I absolutely need to -- if it ain't broke, don't fix it.) :)

Comment: @tim Unfortunately this did not work. I tried the update just before the one mentioned above as well as the oldest driver, I think, for this card as well. Thanks though